# Cannot upload ipa to app store says application is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architectures must be prsent

Tags: iphone, architecture, app-store, ipa

I just made a new app and I cannot upload it to the itunes store, 
I get the following message

**application is missing a required architerture. At least one of the following architectures must be present**

using xcode 4.3.2

Any help on how to fix this will be great!!!!

Comment: IIRC AppStore apps don't come in APKs, that's for Android...

Comment: In iPhone app file extension is .ipa file

Answer (score 2):

In XCode, click on your project (on the left hand side) and then go to your target. Go to the 'Build Settings' tab, and under 'Architectures', you should have `armv6 armv7`. If not, click on whatever is says there, then click 'other' from the menu that pops up, and manually add `armv6` and `armv7` on seperate lines using the plus (+) button in the bottom left of the popup window.

Look at the picture below for an example

[image: Just like this]

Comment: Do you have exactly what I have up there?